# MacPort and py26-mysql os x lion

Tags: mysql, macports

I can't install py26-mysql with macport.

*sudo port install py26-mysql*

and I get

*Error: org.macports.configure for port py26-mysql returned: you must select either mysql4, mysql5, mysql51 or mysql55*

. I have install mysql5 and mysql5-server with mac port. On my mac i have juste mysql5.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: am having this problem as well. . .

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem when installing MySQL adaptor for python. I'm assuming you want to install this package [http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/].

My solution was to install the package through **pip** (a Python Package Installer), which you can get from mac ports. On mac ports there are several versions of pip based on which version of python you're running, for example if you're running python 2.6 the pip package name on macports is:

```
py26-pip
```

and for python 2.7 its:

```
py27-pip
```

Once you've done that you can install the same `py26-mysql` package running the following in the commandline:

```
sudo pip-2.6 install mysql-python
```

(assuming python 2.6)

Hope that helps